# Getting HyperV to work after uninstalling Vmware

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I originally used Vmware on this machine and uninstalled it. I've attempted to enable the HyperV through powershell and the cmdlet with various suggestions I've seen on Google but no luck. Any ideas?
The error is:

### The Hyper_V Mgmt Tools could not access an expected WMI class on computer 'x". This may indicate that the Hyper_V Platform is not installed on the ocmputer or the version of the Hyper-V Platform is incompatible with these management tools.

Comment: Have you enabled the HyperV role via Server Manager, or is that what you're attempting to do here? What version of Windows is this?

Comment: Yes, after uninstalling Vmware I enabled the role via the gui. 2012, having the same issue on Windows 10.

Comment: in the event viewer tells me: The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service terminated with the following error: 
Ran out of memory. also The Virtualization Based Security enablement policy check at phase 0 failed with status: Virtual Secure Mode (VSM) is not initialized. The hypervisor or VSM may not be present or enabled.

Comment: Ok I found out the hyper v services was turned off for some reason. Now I got a new error after being able to connect locally to hyper v.

The application encourtered an error while attempting to change the state of 'X'

'X' Failed to start.

Virtual machine 'X" could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.

Comment: when i enter bcdedit in cmdlet it shows hypervisor is set to auto, and bios is set to have virtualization enabled